# Звонок по клику по номеру телефона, который находится в textView или webView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

TextView содержит текст в котором присутствует **номер телефона**. В атрибутах textView в Detection выбрал Phone Numbers. Таким образом **номер** стал подсвечиваться красный как ссылка, но при долгом нажатии на него происходит ошибка:

*"Warning: Attempt to present <_UIRotatingAlertController: 0x7c985800> on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"*

А при не долгом нажатии тоже выдаёт ошибку:

*"LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme sms"*

Далее я решил поменять textView на webView, где тоже при нажатии на телефон происходит почти та же самая ошибка:

*"Warning: Attempt to present < UIWebRotatingAlertController: 0x79c41000> on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"*

Таким образом никак не могу произвести звонок. Перепробовал различные решения данной задачи, ничего не помогло. Пожалуйста, посоветуйте что-нибудь.

Comment: а пример кода :) Телепатия пока что дорогое удовольствие, так понять сложно в чем ошибка.

Comment: ну чисто для моего душевного спокойствия: вы же это не на симуляторе тестируете?

Comment: Судя по ошибке, в webview ссылка для создания смс. Требуется по этому номеру произвести звонок?